# enquiry.php form only works with .com email addresses

Tags: php, html

The form only works if the user submitting the form is using a .com email address. If the user is using a .com address I receive an email from them containing their form information (content). But, if anyone with another email address for example .co.uk submits the form, it does not send an email to myself (billy@hotmail.co.uk), please help. The enquiry.php code is below:

```
<?php
$email_to = "billy@hotmail.com";
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$telephone = $_POST["telephone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$time = $_POST["time"];

if (empty($firstname)) {
     show_error("Please fill in your Name - hit back in the browser to correct");
}
if (empty($surname)) {
    show_error("Please fill in your Surname - hit back in the browser to correct");
}


if (empty($email)) {
    show_error("Please fill in your Email Address - hit back in the browser to correct");
}

if (empty($telephone)) {
    show_error("Please fill in your Telephone Number - hit back in the browser to correct");
}

if (empty($time)) {
    show_error("Please select a collection time slot - hit back in the browser to correct");
 }


 $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
 if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email)) {
     show_error("E-mail address not valid");
 }


 $email_from = $_POST["email"];
 $message = $_POST["message"];
 $email_subject = "Easter 2018 Order Form";
 $headers =
 "From: $email_from .\n";
 "Reply-To: $email_from .\n";
 $message = 

"First Name: ". $firstname . 
"\r\nSurname: " . $surname . 
"\r\nTelephone Number: " . $telephone . 
"\r\nEmail Address: " . $email . 
"\r\nTime Slot: " . $time . 


 ini_set("sendmail_from", $email_from);
 $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f"  
 .$email_from);
 if ($sent) {
     header("location: 
     http://www.billyfarroll.co.uk/thank-you.html");
 } else {
     echo "There has been an error sending your comments. Please try later.";
 }

function check_input($data, $problem='') {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0) {
      show_error($problem);
   }
   return $data;
}

function show_error($myError) {
?>
```

Comment: _"it does not send an email to myself"_ - do you get any of your error messages instead then?

Comment: I don't know much about regex but I tested your regex `/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/` and it only works for domains ending in `.com` May I suggset switching over to one of many php's built in validations? http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: Do you have the same problem with emails containing numbers?

Comment: `function show_error($myError)
{


?>` - that's a parse error right there. You should show us your real code.

Comment: No, it takes me to the thank-you.html page, but the form information that has been filled out does not get sent through to my email address. But when the user has .com email address, and they do take the exact same procedure the email does get sent through to me.

Comment: Please check email vaildation using this method: `if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    //Email is valid
}`

Comment: @IsThisJavascript imo you tested nothing, because according to its regex it would work with every mail address that are not double dotted after the @.
So anything like @*.* would work, and anything like @*.*.* wouldn't work.
Also i suppose numbers don't work neither

Comment: please take @IsThisJavascript's advice and use the built in filters. Your regex will allow an email-address like `-@-.-`...

Comment: @LilianBarraud I stand corrected. I used the online regex site which wouldn't wrap my `.co.uk` email but when testing in a php environment it does work.

Comment: @billy.farroll It takes you to the 'thankyou' page, because you don't exit the script when you `show_error`. So it keeps on running, tries to send the email. This of course _does not_ answer why you don't receive that email then.

Comment: in your script you send to `$email_to = "billy@hotmail.com";`, but in the text you say `billy@hotmail.co.uk`!?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the text should say 'billy@hotmail.com' not billy@hotmail.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem is with your regex.

The thing is that when you use this regex

```
([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)
```

it will match a result on these kind of address mail

> billy@hotmail.co.uk

but the matched result will be

```
billy@hotmail.co
```

because you're askin for `a_word@a_word.a_word`

So the email address is valid according to your code, but isn't existing

You have to recheck your regex.

Maybe try

```
("/.*@.*\..*/")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help / advice, I'll try now

Comment: @billy.farroll regex are a pain to use if you are not used to. However you can [test your regex online](https://regex101.com/)